# How to convert YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS TO HH:MM:SS IN mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

i have one column (vedu_time) in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format, i required new column (ganta_time)(new) having only HH:MM:SS for all my records at a time.

Please suggest the query.

```
vedu_time           | ganta_time  --> New column
--------------------|------------
2021-12-01 07:12:30 | 07:12:30
2021-12-01 07:20:44 | 07:20:44
2021-12-01 13:11:26 | 13:11:26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a function called [`time()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
UPDATE table SET ganta_time = TIME(vedu_time);
```

will take the time and set it into the gana_time column for all your rows in that table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_format` and put that value in your insert or update query.

```php
$date=date_create("2022-10-14 15:03:23"); // For example purpose 
echo date_format($date,"H:i:s");
```

Output:
`15:03:23`